# What happens to spammers?

Tags: discussion, moderation, spam

Recently there have been a few spam messages. That does neither really surprise nor really shock me. However, what I find a bit strange is that repeated messages cam from [the same user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/7652/lucylovesh) and nobody is taking the appropriate measures.

According to what I have seen elsewhere, I would have expected that spammers are banned and accounts deleted. But here that does not seem to be the case. I have to admit that I am somewhat surprised. For trivia, the moderators are quick on the draw, but regarding spam, there seems to be some tolerance. Is this a feature of the stackexchange family of sites?

Comment: They are caught by drones and fed to unicorns.

Comment: Oh my god. That sounds horrible. I feel sorry for them.

Comment: For unicorns? Or spammers?

Comment: For unicorns of course. What a question!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't one spammer using the same account, but one spammer creating accounts over and over using the same name. Moderators delete spam posts as soon as they encounter them. Be sure to flag spam, moderators may not notice a post that happens to be spam but will notice a flag. Spammer accounts are usually destroyed, either manually or automatically.

Answer (score 2):

What happened in the case that you mentioned is that I initially suspended the user for 7 days for the first infringement, and then for 30 days for the second one. It was then pointed out to me that [spammer accounts can be deleted outright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165306/should-we-delete-spammers-accounts). Since then, I've been deleting accounts (including the one you mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The account still exists. Click on the link in my post

Comment: Odd...I did delete it earlier, so I did that again. Note sure if it was another account with the same name but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Now it's gone :-)